# MultiSelect in AngularJS 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have the below Select box

```
<select multiselect  name="BodyColor.Default" [(ngModel)]="BodyColor.Default">
    <option *ngFor="let z of BodyColor.Options" value={{z.OptionID}}>
        {{z.OptionID}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to save this multiselect if `BodyColor.Default` is of type `string`.

I am using this as part of the JSON structure that I use for displaying data and I cannot change the data type for it.

Or is it just possible to change the datatype of `BodyColor.Default` on demand when i want in the HTML file to array type.

Here is the JSON

```
 "Attributes": [
        {
          "AttributeID": "Body Color",
          "Options": [
            {
              "AttributeID": "Body Color",
              "OptionID": "Aluminum",
              "Description": "Aluminum",
              "Position": 1.000000000,
              "Default": false
            },
            {
              "AttributeID": "Body Color",
              "OptionID": "Black",
              "Description": "Black",
              "Position": 2.000000000,
              "Default": false
            },
            {
              "AttributeID": "Body Color",
              "OptionID": "Blue Cobalt-2747C",
              "Description": "Blue Cobalt-2747C",
              "Position": 3.000000000,
              "Default": false
            },
            {
              "AttributeID": "Body Color",
              "OptionID": "Blue Midnight-295C",
              "Description": "Blue Midnight-295C",
              "Position": 4.000000000,
              "Default": false
            },
            {
              "AttributeID": "Body Color",
              "OptionID": "Blue-Costco-286C",
              "Description": "Blue-Costco-286C",
              "Position": 5.000000000,
              "Default": false
            },
            {
              "AttributeID": "Body Color",
              "OptionID": "Blue-P2955C",
              "Description": "Blue-P2955C",
              "Position": 6.000000000,
              "Default": false
            },
            {
              "AttributeID": "Body Color",
              "OptionID": "Camo",
              "Description": "Camo",
              "Position": 7.000000000,
              "Default": false
            },
            {
              "AttributeID": "Body Color",
              "OptionID": "Chrome",
              "Description": "Chrome",
              "Position": 8.000000000,
              "Default": false
            },
            {
              "AttributeID": "Body Color",
              "OptionID": "Cinnamon",
              "Description": "Cinnamon",
              "Position": 9.000000000,
              "Default": false
            },
            {
              "AttributeID": "Body Color",
              "OptionID": "Copper",
              "Description": "Copper",
              "Position": 10.000000000,
              "Default": false
            },
            {
              "AttributeID": "Body Color",
              "OptionID": "Green-357C",
              "Description": "Green-357C",
              "Position": 11.000000000,
              "Default": false
            },
            {
              "AttributeID": "Body Color",
              "OptionID": "Gunmetal-7C",
              "Description": "Gunmetal-7C",
              "Position": 12.000000000,
              "Default": false
            },
            {
              "AttributeID": "Body Color",
              "OptionID": "N/A",
              "Description": "N/A",
              "Position": 13.000000000,
              "Default": false
            },
            {
              "AttributeID": "Body Color",
              "OptionID": "OD Green-7771C",
              "Description": "OD Green-7771C",
              "Position": 14.000000000,
              "Default": false
            },
            {
              "AttributeID": "Body Color",
              "OptionID": "Onyx",
              "Description": "Onyx",
              "Position": 15.000000000,
              "Default": false
            },
            {
              "AttributeID": "Body Color",
              "OptionID": "Orange",
              "Description": "Orange",
              "Position": 16.000000000,
              "Default": false
            },
            {
              "AttributeID": "Body Color",
              "OptionID": "Pewter-6C",
              "Description": "Pewter-6C",
              "Position": 17.000000000,
              "Default": false
            },
            {
              "AttributeID": "Body Color",
              "OptionID": "Platinum",
              "Description": "Platinum",
              "Position": 18.000000000,
              "Default": false
            },
            {
              "AttributeID": "Body Color",
              "OptionID": "Red-200C",
              "Description": "Red-200C",
              "Position": 19.000000000,
              "Default": false
            },
            {
              "AttributeID": "Body Color",
              "OptionID": "Red-202C",
              "Description": "Red-202C",
              "Position": 20.000000000,
              "Default": false
            },
            {
              "AttributeID": "Body Color",
              "OptionID": "Slate-10C",
              "Description": "Slate-10C",
              "Position": 21.000000000,
              "Default": false
            },
            {
              "AttributeID": "Body Color",
              "OptionID": "Stainless",
              "Description": "Stainless",
              "Position": 22.000000000,
              "Default": false
            },
            {
              "AttributeID": "Body Color",
              "OptionID": "White",
              "Description": "White",
              "Position": 23.000000000,
              "Default": false
            }
          ],
          "Description": "Body Color",
          "InputType": "Multiple Select",
          "Default": "",
          "Required": false,
          "EpicorOnly": false
        },
```

Edit: So what seems to be happening is that it saving the data but throwing this error in AngularJS values.map is not a function. I see AngularJS convert the string into array automatically and saves the value but then later throws this error.

Comment: AngularJs is Angular 1.X, Angular 2 is Angular, edited the tag.

Comment: What does this question have to do with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the datatype to be either string or an array?
Example: `private Testing: string[] | string;`

Comment: Can i change that inside the HTML??

Comment: No. You have to do it in the component.